# How to get the date of a max value from another column in R?

Tags: r

| Date | Temperature | Precipitation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 15/01/2007 | 8 | 1.196 |
| 16/01/2007 | 7 | 1.218 |
| 17/01/2007 | 8 | 1.205 |
| 18/01/2007 | 4 | 1.157 |

This is a similar df to the one I'm working on.

I tried this:

```
df[which(df$Date == "max(df$P)")]
```

and I got this "data frame with 0 columns and 20454 rows"

Then I tried this:

```
which(df$Date == "max(df$P)")
```

And I got this, with way more rows, and I'm sure there is a TRUE somewhere in those +20k rows

```
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
  [13] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
  [25] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Then this one

```
df[max(df$P),)]
```

worked, but it showed the whole row, I am sure there should be another way to output just the date. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `which.max` you could do:

```r
df[which.max(df$P), "Date"] 
#> [1] "16/01/2007"
```

**DATA**

```
df <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
              Date = c("15/01/2007", "16/01/2007", "17/01/2007", "18/01/2007"),
       Temperature = c(8L, 7L, 8L, 4L),
     Precipitation = c(1.196, 1.218, 1.205, 1.157)
)
```

Comment: I didn't think about this, still learning, thanks a lot.